# Rust if let Optionals and compare conditions

Tags: rust

I have a lot of code like this, and would like to replace with a `"if let"` binding for clarity in my case

```
// contrived
fn maybe() -> Option<i32> { Some(1)}
let maybe_num_A = maybe();
let maybe_num_B = maybe();
...
match (maybe_num_A, maybe_num_B) {
  (Some(a) , Some(b)) if a > b => {
      .... 
  }
  _ => {} // don't care many times about the other matches that doesn't hold. how to get rid of this?
}
```

Not sure on the syntax to bind the let with a comparison:

```
if let (Some(a),Some(b) = (maybe_num_A, maybe_num_B) ???&&??? a > b {
   ... 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're only comparing `A` and `B` and do not necessarily need to bind them, you could use the [`.zip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.zip) method that's in [Rust 1.46](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2020/08/27/Rust-1.46.0.html) and apply a [`map_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or) on it, e.g:

```rust
let a: Option<i32> = Some(42);
let b: Option<i32> = Some(-42);

if a.zip(b).map_or(false, |(a, b)| a > b) {
   // 42 is greater than -42
}
```

If either of the two values is `None`, it will default to `false`.

Answer (score 3):

> Not sure on the syntax to bind the let with a comparison:

Unfortunately there isn't any. If you need to access bindings from the pattern, you have to do it the old fashioned way:

```
if let (Some(a), Some(b)) = (maybe_num_A, maybe_num_B) {
    if a > b {
         ...
    }
}
```

If you don't need the bindings from the pattern then [Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64522523/493729) will do the job and might end up cleaner, as long as the actual patterns are relatively simple.

Comment: Hi do you know if multiple conditions are still required in the latest versions of rust. It seems like the kind of thing they may have added support for in the past few years.